# How to partially manage a resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

`CloudFormation` import can be made to partially manage a resource (since CloudFormation has no natural drift detection). This allows us to do something like this:

1. `CloudFormation` Template 1 creates a `vpc-1`, `route-tables-1` etc. So it sort of owns it.
2. Each person in the team has their own `vpc`, route tables etc. and they manage it via their personal `CloudFormation` templates. Say these are templates A, B, C ...
3. When they want to peer their `vpc` with `vpc-1` and modify `route-tables-1` to allow connection between the vpcs they simply update their template to import `vpc-1` and do the necessary modifications in their own template. So you might have connections and routing between `vpc-1 <-> vpc-A` set up by developer A using their `CloudFormation` template-A. Similarly `vpc-1 <-> vpcB` is created by developer B and so on.
4. The developers can destroy their respective stacks. All that will do is remove the peering connection and modify the route tables in `vpc-1` to remove just that bit which routed traffic from `vpc-1` to their vpc. Other things remain untouched. E.g if dev-A destroys their stack, it's not going to affect `vpc-1 <-> vpc-B` bits which pertains to dev-B

I'm having to deal with terraform now to create yet another vpc, say `vpc-z`. As I understand terraform always tries to sync the state entirely according to its world-view - i.e there is automatic drift-detection + correction on running terraform apply/destroy. So if I create a `vpc-z` using `terraform` and want to peer with `vpc-1` above (and modify its route tables to allow traffic), I think I'll need to import the `vpc` and route-table resources. However once I do that, `terraform` will always ensure that that state at the time of import is maintained. Now if developer-A tears down their stack and removes the routing configuration from `vpc-1 <-> vpc-A`, the next time I apply `terraform`, will it detect that some routes have changed in `vpc-1` (since the time it was imported here) and will it try to fix them back (and likely fail)?

In short can I ask `terraform` to reference an existing resource, modify certain aspect of it and care only about those aspects during future apply/destroy and not other things which might have been changed by someone else (either manually or through a different `CloudFormation`/`Terraform` template etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I think I'll need to import the vpc and route-table resources"

I believe that assumption is incorrect. You can use a [data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources) for both the [VPC](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc), and the [route-table](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route_table) resources, and just have Terraform manage new [route](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route) resources. Data sources allow you to have Terraform look up existing resources without managing them, for the purposes of referencing them in other resources that Terraform does manage.

Comment: Ah I see, ta! So basically I use the data-source for "other" vpc to get its id for peering with my vpc and then use data-source again to get the other vpc's various route tables (possibly filtered by subnet) and then use their ids to associate the new route resources with? If true is that not considered modifying the route-tables of the other vpc (which data-source wouldn't allow being read-only)?

Comment: Terraform can have routes directly in the route table resource (for route tables you are managing via Terraform) and separate route resources (see the thing I linked) for routes managed by Terraform in a route table not managed by Terraform. It doesn't matter that you used a read-only datasource to look up the route table, since the route resource itself is not read-only.

Comment: Just be aware that you can still run into conflicts with routes managed in two separate Terraform templates. The other Terraform code that manages the actual route table needs to define all the routes separately, as separate `aws_route` resources, instead of embedding them in the `aws_route_table` resource.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The other route-table is managed by cloudformation, and that doesn't have much notion of drift detection (unless you specifically ask it to and even then it's flaky and we don't use it much anyway) - it'll just compare it with the template and be happy if it doesn't see any changes to it, irrespective of what happened outside its knowledge to the actual resource. So I think if your suggestion works, I'm golden for now.